# Conditional key binding: Evil vs Slime conflict for "M-."

Tags: key-bindings, evil, slime

Slime (and elisp-slime-nav) uses `M-.` to navigate to the symbol at point, and `M-,` to pop back to previous marks. I like this.

Evil uses `.` to repeat the previous editing command, `C-.` to replace a just repeated command with a previously executed command, and `M-.` to do the same in the reverse direction (useful if you overshoot with `C-.`). I like this as well.

I'd like to use `M-.` for slime-style navigation except when the previous command was `C-.` (`evil-repeat-pop`), in which case I'd like `M-.` to run `evil-repeat-pop-next`. I'm not sure how to go about implementing this.

I'm considering removing the evil `M-.` binding and defining a [hydra](https://github.com/abo-abo/hydra) that's entered upon running `evil-repeat-pop` (`C-.`) and which binds `M-.` to `evil-repeat-pop-next` in a transient keymap.

I also considered binding `M-.` to a wrapper function like,

```
(if (eql last-command 'evil-repeat-pop)
    (evil-repeat-pop-next)
  (elisp-slime-nav-find-elisp-thing-at-point))
```

but I want the "else" clause to do whatever `M-.` would have done if evil wasn't enabled. This might be `elisp-slime-nav-find-elisp-thing-at-point`, `xref-find-definitions`, `ggtags-find-tag-dwim`, etc. depending on what modes and code-tagging approaches I'm using.

Comment: The Hydra way (or the equivalent with a transient keymap) sounds like the better option.  What is the question, exactly?

Answer (score 5):

> I also considered binding M-. to a wrapper function [...] but I want the "else" clause to do whatever M-. would have done if evil wasn't enabled.

You could bind it to a conditional binding, the manual explains it for menu items, but it works for key bindings as well, [(elisp) Extended Menu Items](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Extended-Menu-Items.html):

> the extended format binding looks like this:
>
> ```el
>  (menu-item ITEM-NAME REAL-BINDING
>      . ITEM-PROPERTY-LIST)
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> `:filter FILTER-FN`
>
> ```el
>  This property provides a way to compute the menu item dynamically.
>  The property value FILTER-FN should be a function of one argument;
>  when it is called, its argument will be REAL-BINDING.  The
>  function should return the binding to use instead.
>
>  Emacs can call this function at any time that it does redisplay or
>  operates on menu data structures, so you should write it so it can
>  safely be called at any time.
> ```

(see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/36684318/319698)

Something like this: (not sure if you would need bind in a different keymap than `global-map` since you're using `evil`)

```el
(define-key global-map (kbd "M-.")
  `(menu-item "" evil-repeat-pop :filter
              ,(lambda (cmd) (if (eq last-command 'evil-repeat-pop) cmd))))
```

---

The transient keymap approach might make more sense for your case though.

Answer (score 3):

For what it may be worth, the solution suggested above did not work in its original form but it works with `evil-normal-state-map`:

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "M-.")
  `(menu-item "" evil-repeat-pop :filter
              ,(lambda (cmd) (if (eq last-command 'evil-repeat-pop) cmd))))
```